# Less file import from node_modules doesn't work after building application

Tags: reactjs, vite, antd

I want to overwrite some ant design styles. so I created less file which has imports like this:

```
@import "antd/es/style/themes/default.less";
@import "antd/dist/antd.less";
```

It works perfectly when I run npm start. but when building it doesn;t imports that two files.

vite config looks like this:

```
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      less: {
        math: "always",
        relativeUrls: true,
        javascriptEnabled: true,
      },
    },
  },
```

I've tried import from

> @import "@node-modules/antd/es/style/themes/default.less"

but it can't find file. Somehow it works only when i'm importing

> @import "antd/es/style/themes/default.less"

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Is there any error?